# How do you return a specfic column value of a certain row in an existing table within a database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, case, case-when

**The Problem:**

I'm working in PostgreSQL 9.0 and I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to tackle the situation where you want to return a specific column value of a certain row for use in a CASE WHEN THEN statement.

I want to basically go in and set the value of table A: someRow's someColumn value, equal to the value of table B: row X's column A value, given the value of row X's column B. (More detail in "Backround Info" if needed to understand the question)

This is what I want to do (but don't know how):

```
Update tableA
Set someColumn 
    CASE WHEN given_info_column = 'tableB: row X's column B value' 
    THEN (here I want to return row X's column A value, finding row X using the given column B value) 
    ELSE someColumn END
```

**Background Info: (Optional, for clarification)**

Imagine that there is a user activity table, and a device table in an already existing database, with already existing activity performed strings that exist throughout to codebase you are working in: (for example)

```
User_Activity:
id (int) | user_name (string)    | activity_preformed (string)            | category (string) 
---------|-----------------------|----------------------------------------|------------------
1        | Joe Martinez          | checked out iphone: iphone2            | dvc_activity
2        | Jon Shmoe             | uploads video from device: (id: 12345) | dvc_activity
3        | Larry David           | goes to the bathroom                   |other_activity

Device:
seq (int)| device_name (string)  | device_srl_num (int) | device_status (string)|
---------+-----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
1        | iphone1               | 12344                | available
2        | iphone2               | 12345                | checked out
3        | android1              | 23456                | available
```

Your assignment from your boss is to create a report that shows one table with all device activity, like so:

```
Device Activity Report
(int)     (int)    (string)       (string)                                 (string)      (int)         (string)
act_seq  |usr_id | usr_name     | act_performed                         |  dvc_name | dvc_srl_num | dvc_status  
---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+------------
1        |1      | Joe Martinez | Checked out iphone: iphone2           | iphone2   | 12345       | checked out 
2        |2      | John Shmoe   | uploads video from device: (id: 12345)| android1  | 23456       | available
```

For the purposes of this question, this has to be done by adding a new column to the user activity table called dvc_seq which will be a foreign key to the device table. You will create a temporary table by querying from the user activity table and joining the two where User_Activity (dvc_seq) = Device (seq)

This is fine and will work great for new entries into the User_Activity table, which will record a dvc_seq linking to the associated device **if** the activity involves a device.

The problem is that you need to go in and fill in values for the new dvc_seq column in the User_Activity table for all previous entries relating to devices. Since the previous programmers decided to specify which device in the activity_performed column using the serial number certain times and the device names other times, this presents an interesting problem, where you will need to derive the associated Device seq number from a device, given its name or serial number.

So once again, what I want to do: (using this example)

```
UPDATE User_Activity 
    SET dvc_seq 
    CASE WHEN activity_performed LIKE 'checked out iphone:%' 
    THEN (seq column of Device table) 
        WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM Device WHERE device_name = (substring in place of the %))
    ELSE dvc_seq (I think this would be null since there would be nothing here yet)  
    END
```

Can any of you help me accomplish this?? Thanks in advance for all responses and advice!

Comment: Im not sure if i want to help you teach my Iphone track my bathroom break, But could you create a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aad73)  with your data? That will help a lot.

Comment: To do this we need to know how parse your `activity_performed` column. Can we check first appear of char `:` and try to see if there is and `id` or a `device_name` after that? or do `dvc_name` column can have space?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Honestly I haven't given that part much though yet. The `dvc_name` could have spaces, `"android 3"` would be a valid entry for example. Definitely going to have to parse that string like you said but for now I'm more concerned with how to return a column value of the specific row in question. Regardless of how you parse it, returning a column value of a specific row should be the same right?

Comment: Without a detail sample of what you have is imposible for me to help you. I can only give you general guidelines. If you need help with the pseudo code in my answer let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below uses an update-join to update the sequence number when the serial number or the name is contained within the activity_performed

```
UPDATE UserActivity
SET a.dvc_seq = b.seq
FROM UserActivity AS a
JOIN devices b 
    ON UserActivity.activity_performed LIKE '%from device: (id: ' || b.serial_num || '%'
    OR UserActivity.activity_performed LIKE '%: ' || b.name || '%'
```

Comment: I tought about that, but maybe `b.serial_num` and `b.name` could appear on other part of  `a.activity_performed` and not as deviceID

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I added some prefixes to lower the possibility of false positives

Comment: @FuzzyTree Thanks for your help, this query is the closest I've gotten but is still giving me problems... When testing this query, it updated every entry in the User Activity table instead of just the entrys where activity_performed looks like the two strings in your code. Every entry also is getting filled with the same dvc_seq number. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `name` and `serial_num` for the `dvc_seq` that is being filled for all entries? Are either of them blank?

Comment: Update: I got it to work by adding an additional WHERE clause at the end like so: `WHERE UserActivity.activity_performed LIKE '%from device: (id: ' || b.serial_num || '%' OR UserActivity.activity_performed LIKE '%: ' || b.name || '%';` Thanks again @FuzzyTree , I'm going to mark this answer as the one that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional update on how to speed up this code based off of the correct answer given by @FuzzyTree (this would only work for the serial number, which has a standard length, and not for the device name which could be many different sizes)

Because of the LIKE used in the join, the query runs very slow for large databases. an even better solution would utilize the postgres `substring()` and `position()` functions and join the tables on the serial number like so:

```
UPDATE UserActivity
SET a.dvc_seq = b.seq
FROM UserActivity AS a
JOIN devices b 
    ON b.serial_num = 
    substring(activity_performed from position('%from device: (id: ' in activity_performed)+(length of the string before the plus so that position returns the start position for the serial number)) for (lengthOfSerialNumberHere)) 
WHERE UserActivity.activity_performed LIKE '%from device: (id: ' || b.serial_num || '%';`
```

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql you can't do a complex CASE expresion like

```
CASE WHEN activity_performed LIKE 'checked out iphone:%'
```

only

```
CASE WHEN 1, 2
```

The best you can do is create a function

```
UPDATE User_Activity 
SET dvc_seq = getDeviceID(User_Activity.activity_preformed);
```

Here you can do IF, CASE much easier

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getDeviceID(activity text)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    device_name text;
    device_id   integer;

BEGIN
    -- parse the string activity 

    /* this part is pseudo code
    set device_id;
    IF (device_id is null)
       set device_name;
       search for device_id using device_name;
       set device_id;
    */
    RETURN device_id;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION get_box(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```